# How to filter window function with sum in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, analytics

How do I write this query to filter only sums that are above 50? I can't get this to work with having or sum but I'm sure there's some way.

```
select name, sum(score) 
    from submissions inner join hacker on submissions.hacker_id = hacker.hacker_id
    group by submissions.hacker_id
    order by sum(score) desc
    having sum(score) > 50
```

Fiddle with tables are here (there's nothing unusual about them, this query runs without the last line but returns everybody's scores and names): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a660d/16

Comment: Typically, we'd GROUP BY any and all non-aggregated columns identified within a SELECT, rather than simply relying on a (supposed) functional dependency (that may not in fact exist)

Comment: The exercise asks me to return only names of people with scores above 50 and their scores but I have to join on hacker_id which is the common column between the names and submissions tables. Not really sure what functional dependency means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order by should be after your having. i.e.

```sql
select 
    name, 
    sum(score) 
from 
    submissions 
inner join 
    hacker on submissions.hacker_id = hacker.hacker_id
group by 
    submissions.hacker_id
having 
    sum(score) > 50 
order by 
    sum(score) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Order by should be in last

```
select name, sum(score) 
from submissions 
inner join hacker on submissions.hacker_id = hacker.hacker_id
group by submissions.hacker_id
having sum(score) > 50 
order by sum(score) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a CASE in the sum-statement. This approach works in a windows function, although I have not tested it for the normal sum aggregate function
Option 1 (Case in aggregate sum):

```
select name, sum(case when score>50 else 0 end) 
from submissions inner join hacker on submissions.hacker_id = hacker.hacker_id
group by submissions.hacker_id
order by sum(score) desc
```

Option 2 Windows function:

```
select name, 
sum(case when score>50 else 0 end) over (partition by submissions.hacker_id)
from submissions inner join hacker on submissions.hacker_id = hacker.hacker_id
group by submissions.hacker_id
```

The order by clause changes a bit so I left it out but you can always add it again